# vCard sent to my android from an iPhone arrives as text message

Tags: contacts, ios, vcard

Is there any easy way to save a contact which has arrived like

```
<Subject: PXT> - BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
PRODID blah blah blah
```

Into the contacts?  I believe it happens when someone "shares" a contact with you from iPhone.  If there is only the number or email there it is pretty easy to dig the details out of the text message, but if it sends a small profile picture that comes in decoded as a massive text message which is quite annoying.  It would be nice to have a way to import that text message into a contact, with the avatar and all.

Comment: Yes, I know this.  But vCardIO simply doesn't work for me, I've tried for hours to get it to do what is advertises but it doesn't ..

Comment: alright. what about the other?

Comment: No, I don't want to pay for something simple as this ..

Comment: Did you try [vCard Manager Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.hsrco.vcard&hl=en)? The app looks useful but I haven't tested it myself.

Comment: I tried it now, it's all about sending vCards and doesn't help with receiving them.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug on the OS ([src](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2412))

You have to use a third party app for this. [vCardIO](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=vcard.io&hl=en) and [bizCard Manager/SMS vCard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.mrpear.vcardmanager&hl=en) are good solutions. Former one is preferable and it's free.